# Find a subset of the real numbers

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, real-numbers

I have to find an open and dense subset of the real numbers with arbitrarily small measure.

Since the set of the rational numbers is dense, could we use a subset of the rationals??

How could I find such  a subset, that the measure is arbitrarily small??

Comment: A good starting question for you: Are the rationals open in the real numbers?  If not, then you cannot use a subset of them.

Comment: @Keaton The irrationals are not open in the real numbers, but you can use a subset of them.

Comment: Yes, I understand that they are not open, I was trying to give a hint rather than the solution.  But the problem asks for an open and dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  No subset of the rationals would be open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the rationals to construct this subset, take a enumeration for the rationals $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ and then construct the sets $M_i=(q_i-c2^{-i},q_i+c2^{-i})$, where $c>0$.

If you performe the union of these sets $M=\cup_iM_i$, it will be open, dense and the measure $\mu(M)\leq c$. Since you can take any $c>0$ you have arbitrarrily small measure.

Comment: What do you mean by ``...take an enumeration for the rationals`` ??

Comment: @MaryStar A bijective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. Such function exists since $\mathbb{Q}$ is enumerable.

Comment: I understand!! Thank you very much!!! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Let $\varepsilon_{r}>0$ for each $r\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Then $\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\left(r-\varepsilon_{r},r+\varepsilon_{r}\right)$
is a dense and open set with $\lambda\left(\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\left(r-\varepsilon_{r},r+\varepsilon_{r}\right)\right)\leq2\sum_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\varepsilon_{r}$
.

Here $\sum_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\varepsilon_{r}$ can be "made"
as small as you like.

Comment: I understand!!! Can $\sum_{r \in \mathbb{Q}}\varepsilon_r$ be made as small as we like, because we choose $\varepsilon_r$ to be an arbitrarily small number??

Comment: @MaryStar Technically you have to be careful; you need to find a sequence of positive numbers whose sum is very small. As a result $\varepsilon_r$ will need to depend on $r$. The easiest way to do this is to enumerate the rationals and then exploit the geometric series. This is what Pedro did.

Comment: What is the difference from the set of Pedro and the set of drhab?? Aren`t they the same??

Comment: @MaryStar It comes to the same principle, but the sets are not *exactly* the same. You can recognize in Pedro's answer some special case of this answer. In my answer the epsilons have more freedom.

Comment: @drhab I see... Thank you very much!!! :-)